# jq replace string in array with another string

Tags: jq

let's say I have an array as such:

`["arn:123456:layer:my-layer:5", "arn:123456:layer:their-layer:1"]`

I would like to replace `"arn:123456:layer:my-layer:5"` with `"arn:123456:layer:my-layer:8"` and I need to identify which element I want to replace the last portion of by specifying a regular expression on `.*my-layer.*`

So far I have:

`cat a.json | jq '.[] | (select(test(".*my-layer.*")) | sub(":5";":8";"i"))`

but of course this gives me back only the singular element I replaced:

`"arn:123456:layer:my-layer:8"`

But I need it to give me the original array with just that 1 element changed.

Thanks

Comment: You could split at the colons, check the last two fields, then update if necessary, and rejoin on colons: `map(./":" | select((.[-2] | test("my-layer")) and (.[-1] == "5"))[-1] = "8" | join(":"))`

Answer (score 1):

The question is highly ambiguous, so here are two solutions to two of the many possible disambiguations:

```
map(sub( ":my-layer.*";  ":my-layer:8"))
```

```
(first( range(0;length) as $i | .[$i] | select(test("my-layer:[0-9]*$")) | $i) // null) as $i
| if $i then .[$i] |= sub( ":my-layer:.*";  ":my-layer:8") else . end
```